# If $I$ is an interval of $\Bbb{R}$, $f: I \to \Bbb{R}$ connected and $\forall y \in I\; f^{-1}(\{y\})$ closed in $I$ then $f$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

I have found this theorem in a calculus book

> We say a function $f: I \to \Bbb{R}$, $I$ interval of $\Bbb{R}$ is connected if $\forall J \subseteq I$, with $J$ interval, $f(J)$ is an interval. Prove that if $f$ is connected and if $\forall y \in \Bbb{R} \, f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a closed set *in the relative topology of* $I$, then $f$ is continuous.

I have no idea where I can start, can you give me some hints?

Comment: To the OP: I would recommend adding the topology tag. This is a question that seems more suited toward a topological answer than a calculus-type of answer. (I have ideas from topology on how to approach this problem, but I personally am not sure how I’d be using strictly calculus topics to approach this problem. Hence my first question; you could be taking the two courses concurrently and mixed up the titles.)

Comment: @Clayton if you can solve it using topology it's good too. Perhaps the problem is that I cannot distinguish between calculus and mathematical analysis since in my main language the latter is used to indicate both; but having seen some foreign books of both, I'm quite confident the one I use is a calculus book. I'm sorry for any misunderstandings due to this semantical problem...

Comment: Note: anyway, I'm still a student and I've not begun studying mathematical analysis yet...

Comment: Can you state a few of the topological definitions/theorems that you have available? I assume you know the “inverse image of an open set is open” characterization for continuous functions?

Comment: $I$ is $[0,1]$ ? An interval can be half-open as well?

Comment: @Clayton I know that $f: D \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is continuous $\iff$ $\forall X,\; \text{X open set of } \Bbb{R} \; f^{-1}(X) = f^\leftarrow(X)$ *is opened in the relative topology of* $D$ and that holds also if we replace "opened" with "closed". Anyway, I have some elementary general topology knowledge and the book states some of them (actually, three chapters of it are dedicated to topology...).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It can be... as interval I mean a connected set in $\Bbb{R}$. So every subset of $\Bbb{R}$ that can't be included as the disjoint union of two sets is an interval. In other words: $I \, \text{interval} \iff \nexists A_1, A_2 \subseteq \Bbb{R} \, \text{with} \, A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset : \, I \subseteq A_1 \cup A_2$. Basically any set in the form $(a,b), (a,b^{'}], [a^{'},b), [a^{'},b^{'}]$ with $ a,b \in \overset{\sim}{\Bbb{R}} $ and $a^{'}, b^{'} \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: @Clayton I've realized now that I have not replied you with a list of topology topics. My book deals with properties of open and closed sets as well as their properties such as a closed set contains its accumulation points. The inverse image of an opened set is opened if the function is continuous is one of the theorems. I also got to hear the Heine-Borel theorem about compactness of closed and limited sets of $\Bbb{R}$. What it does not explain rigorously and deeply, however, is the general notion of topology over a set and topological spaces in general

Comment: I’m still thinking about your problem. This has been a very busy day for me (it is test day for my students and our copier broke), so I have not sat down with your problem at all. I only have the idea to start by contradiction and hope it leads somewhere.

Comment: This is a good question. I am looking forward to an answer, as I am having trouble coming up with one.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the condition that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed in $I$ must play a role as Conway's base 13 function would cause trouble otherwise.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function

Comment: I noticed I've written some details of the problem in the title but not in the question. I'm rewriting the problem putting everything in the question and not in the title. Basically I copied the fact that I is an interval from the title to the theorem and I've pointed out that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed for all real values of $y$, thus removing any sort of accidental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x \in I$ let $I_n(x) = I \cap (x - \frac{1}{n},x + \frac{1}{n})$. This is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $I$. We have
$$(*) \phantom{xx} \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f(I_n(x)) = \{ f(x) \} .$$
"$\supset$" is trivial. To verify "$\subset$", let $y \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f(I_n(x))$. Then there exist $x_n \in I_n(x)$ such that $f(x_n) = y$. Obviously $x_n \to x$. Since $f^{-1}(y)$ is closed in $I$ , we see that $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, i.e. $f(x) = y$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $I_n(x)$ is an interval, also $J_n = f(I_n(x))$ is an interval. We have $J_n = \langle a_n,b_n \rangle$, where $\langle a_n,b_n \rangle$ stands for an open, half-open or closed interval such that $a_n \le f(x) \le b_n$. $a_n = -\infty$, $b_n = \infty$ is allowed. The sequence $(a_n)$ is increasing, the sequence $(b_n)$ decreasing. But $(*)$ shows that $a_n, b_n \to f(x)$, hence $f(I_n(x)) = J_n \subset (f(x)- \varepsilon, f(x)+ \varepsilon)$ for sufficiently large $n$. This means that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Very good proof. I've just skimmed through it and I've understood pretty much everything. I will look in more details into it in the next few days. Thanks!